# Does SharePoint in any way support Wiki markup languages?

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, markup

I tend to think the answer is no.  There is so much noise with these search terms that I am having problems coming up with a definitive answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

SharePoint Wiki out of the box does not support 'full' standard wiki markup languages. (Most commonly the "[[page]]" markup is the only utilized wiki markup in SharePoint wikis). This is one of the foremost complaints with the SharePoint wiki.

Comment: Have you looked at the codeplex link?  Some interesting stuff.

Comment: For the enhanced wiki, yes. We use an alternative one from KwizCom. Not bad. Though the PM for the vNext SharePoint wiki is on twitter and REALLY listening to everyone's feedback.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to edit your shared documents using markdown there is a workaround.

You can use the excellent opensource [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor and save your documents as html:

1. Edit your document
2. Open the markdown preview (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
3. Right click in the preview pane, select *Save As .html* (you must save as file, not copy as .html)
4. Open the file, copy the contents

Then, on the sharepoint site, you paste the doc as HTML:

1. Select 'Edit this page'
2. Click edit source
3. Paste the html text
4. Click OK

The only shortcoming is that if others are editing the same page you won't be able to convert the page from html back to markdown; it's a one-way process only.

Comment: You can use standard [Pandoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc) for Markdown to html conversion.